# Black-Scholes Theory vs Actual Market Price

Tags: option-pricing, black-scholes

I have a question of which I am uncertain on how to answer, that is:

---

Assume the Black and Scholes differential equation for option pricing with constant risk free rate, $ r $ and constant volatility $ \sigma^2 $. For a new type of *q-option*, the defined payout at $ t = T $ is

$$
G_q(S,T) = (S-E)^2 \theta(S-E).
$$

At time $ t $ the price of the underlying asset is found to be $ S_1 $. You consider to buy a *q-option* with $ T-t = 30 $  days at a strike price $ E = 1.2S_1 $. Without explicitly calculating the price of the option $ G_q(S,t) $ for an arbitrary time $ t $, would you expect that the price of this *q-option* underestimates or overestimates the market price for this specific option? That is, would you expect to pay more or less for the considered *q-option* as compared to the theoretical price?

---

Is the answer to this question just that the theoretical price neither over- nor underestimates the market price? That is, per definition they should be the same?

Comment: The market does not believe that $r$ and $\sigma^2$ are constant, the theoretician in this question assumes that they are. The prices they set will be different.

Comment: @noob2 Given what you are saying, in general, would this mean that the theoretical price is lower or higher than actual price?

Comment: First find out (in your lecture notes or textbook) how **for a vanilla option** the BS price and the market price differ (hint: it depends whether $S>E$ or $S<E$). Then from this fact draw a conclusion about the situation for **this strange option** called a q-option.